# Stack content for g++4.8

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly, gdb, stack-overflow

I have written this simple piece of code for testing buffer overflow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int f(int x, int y, char *s){
   char buf[4];
   strcpy(buf,s);
   return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv){
   f(2,3,argv[1]);
   return 0;
}
```

Then compiling and viewing its execution with gdb (g++ 4.8.4)

```
g++ -g -fno-stack-protector -o bo bo.c
gdb bo
...
   b f
   r  "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
   p $rbp // 0x7fffffffdc90
   p $rsp // 0x7fffffffdc70
   x/20xw $rsp
     0x7fffffffdc70:    0xffffe0ef  0x00007fff  0x00000003  0x00000002
     0x7fffffffdc80:    0xffffdcb0  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000000
     0x7fffffffdc90:    0xffffdcb0  0x00007fff  0x00400585  0x00000000
     0x7fffffffdca0:    0xffffdd98  0x00007fff  0x00000000  0x00000002
     0x7fffffffdcb0:    0x00000000  0x00000000  0xf7a36ec5  0x00007fff
```

My understanding is that the stack *grows downward* to lower addresses, but it looks this stack frame (from `0x7fffffffdc90 - 0x7fffffffdc90`) is growing upward: the parameters are pushed upward (s, y then x). Why is that?

Looks like the return address (0x00400585) is pushed first. But what are the meanings of subsequent words? Are they:

- Saved `$rbp$`?
- What are the next 2 words?

Comment: Aren't you using Sys V AMD64 ABI?

Comment: Don't confuse the way the stack is managed (what push/pop) do with GDB's presentation; the e*x*amine command will always print addresses in ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what happens to your stack after the call of `f`, call disassembler in gdb:

```
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function f(int, int, char*):
   0x000000000040052d <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040052e <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400531 <+4>: sub    $0x20,%rsp
   0x0000000000400535 <+8>: mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400538 <+11>:    mov    %esi,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x000000000040053b <+14>:    mov    %rdx,-0x20(%rbp)
   0x000000000040053f <+18>:    mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rdx
   0x0000000000400543 <+22>:    lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400547 <+26>:    mov    %rdx,%rsi
   0x000000000040054a <+29>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
=> 0x000000000040054d <+32>:    callq  0x400410 <strcpy@plt>
   0x0000000000400552 <+37>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400557 <+42>:    leaveq 
   0x0000000000400558 <+43>:    retq
```

Before the call to `strcpy` the stack looks like (I use 64bit formating rather than 32bit):

```
(gdb) x/6xg $rsp
0x7fffffffddb0: 0x00007fffffffe297  0x0000000200000003
0x7fffffffddc0: 0x00007fffffffddf0  0x0000000000000000
0x7fffffffddd0: 0x00007fffffffddf0  0x0000000000400585
```

So you can see:

1. `0x0000000000400585` - return address of the function `f`.
2. right next to it `0x00007fffffffddf0` - pushed on the stack by `0x000000000040052d <+0>:   push   %rbp`
3. the next 4 values were reserved on stack via
      `0x0000000000400531 <+4>:    sub    $0x20,%rsp`
4. you can see parameters `2` and `3` being saved on the stack prior to the call of the `strcpy` (`0x0000000200000003`- because `int`s are only 4 byte long).

You can also deduce other values on the stack from the disassembly.

The top of the stack is at the beginning (address `0x7fffffffddb0`) and the addresses get bigger (e.g. `0x7fffffffddd0` for the third line) so you can see the stack really grows downwards but is shown upside down by gdb.

Comment: don't arguments get pushed before the returned addresses? And why is this that gdb shows upside-down addresses?

Comment: @user1734905 it is Sys V AMD64 ABI, so the arguments are in registers `edi`, `esi` and `rdx`. They have to be saved to stack prior to the call of `strcpy` otherwise the values can get lost. You have no optimization, so the compiler doesn't care, that you don't need these values afterwards and saves them anyway.